# SWT Composite Transform

Tags: java, swt, composite

I can find neither a solution nor whether it is even possible to easily transform a Composite in SWT.

I'm trying to implement zooming in/out with CTRL+SCROLL over a Composite. What I found thus far is adding a PaintListener to a composite, like this:

```
    this.viewingFrame = new Shell(new Display());
    this.viewingFrame.setLayout(new GridLayout(2, false));
    GridDataFactory.fillDefaults().grab(true, true).applyTo(viewingFrame);

    c1 = new Composite(viewingFrame, SWT.NONE);
    GridLayoutFactory.swtDefaults().applyTo(c1);
    GridDataFactory.swtDefaults().align(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL).grab(true, true).applyTo(c1);
    c1.addPaintListener(new PaintListener() {

        @Override
        public void paintControl(PaintEvent e) {
            Transform trans = new Transform(e.display);
            e.gc.setAdvanced(true); // After this line a call to e.gc.getAdvance() returns true
            trans.scale(1.5f, 1.5f);
            e.gc.setTransform(trans);
            trans.dispose();
        }
    });
    // Of course there is more code. I have a KTable displaying a 2D map. I also tried adding the PaintListener to the shell, the composite c1 and the KTable. Same result.
```

However this doesn't work. While debugging I could see that the listener is called but there is no visible effect.

I'm a novice with regard to SWT but I learn fast so I'm willing to consider complex solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is: scaling controls in SWT is not supported (directly). The `Transform` applies only to the drawing operations that are done on the GC for which it was created. It does not affect the controls that are contained in the Composite.

To emulate scaling to a cretain degree, you can change the font size of the container whose content should scale (i.e. the `Shell` or a `Composite`) and then re-layout. The font size is *inherited* by contained controls unless a font was explicitly set. In the latter case you would have to change the size of these fonts as well.

If you want the `Shell` to grow/shrink with its content you will have to `pack()` it. Otherwise you likely need to place a `ScrolledComposite` within the Shell that contains all the actual content.

BTW use the `Canvas` widget instead of a `Composite` if you actually want to draw something.

Comment: Thanks for explaining this and suggesting a solution. This isn't exactly what I wanted but I think I can make it work for my needs.